# read_xlsx function fails to import online dataset with valid url

Tags: r

(NB- I am very much a beginner in R.)
This is the code I tried:

```
read_xlsx("valid/url")
```

For some reason I get the error message:

```
'path' does not exist:'valid/url'
```

I know the URL works, I have tested it many times. I am mystified, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how much we can help without having a valid URL. Is there another URL you can use that is public (no private information) and is not small, yet produces the same problem for you?

Comment: Just tried library `openxlsx` `read.xlsx` and worked for an online file: `df = read.xlsx('https://www.wisdomaxis.com/technology/software/data/for-reports/Orders-With%20Nulls.xlsx')`

Comment: If you read [`?read_xlsx`](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/reference/read_excel.html) (assuming `readxl` here), it says that the first argument `path=` is just that, a path. Most functions that do accept URLs typically say as such (e.g., `read.csv`). There was an issue requesting this feature ([readxl#183](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/183)), but it was closed some time ago; there is recent discussion on that note ([readxl#278](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/278)) that is still open, perhaps it will be supported in the future.

Comment: Please also edit your your question to add the name of the package you are using. THX :-)

Comment: Until then, I think Nadia's suggestion to use `download.file` first is your option. If you really want a one-stop-function, you can always write your own function that first checks `if (file.exists(...)) else { download.file(...); ...; }`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your issue correctly, I think you are inputting the URL into the read_xlsx command.  Far as I am aware, this will not work if your excel file is online, you will need to download it locally first.

I suggest the following adjustment:

```
url <- "valid/url"
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(url, temp, mode="wb")
df1 <- read_excel(path = temp)
```

This will download the excel file into a temporary file, which you can then read into a dataframe, since it will be saved locally.